# Drones powered by hydrogen cells

Tags: recommendations

I'm looking for a power source to travel long distances, and in this I saw that drones powered by hydrogen cells are emerging.
I looked for it but the available information I found is very incomplete and inconclusive.

I would like to know where i can buy or how I do that and how to identify the efficiency or cost-benefit of a hydrogen cell to see if it pays to use it in projects.

[Innovative Fuel Cell Plus Standard DC Modules Yield Compact, Long-Flying Drone](https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/innovative-fuel-cell-plus-standard-dc-modules)

Any reference is valid!